# Prove that the size of $G$ is at least $\frac{n² − 2n}{4}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ that has exactly two connected components, both of them
being complete graphs. Prove that the size of $G$ is at least $\frac{n² − 2n}{4}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well rather $n$ being the order of your whole graph, you should introduce $k$ the order of one component. What would then be the order of the other component?

Comment: the other component order will be n-k, and there size ll be  k = $\frac{(n1² − n1)}{2}$ and n-k = $\frac{(n2² − n2)}{2}$

Comment: Your equality is not really an equality. I guess you were mapping each order with a corresponding size.

Comment: exactly i want to use the size of each component to proof the size of g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the connected components $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ have $k$ and $n-k$ vertices respectively. Then the number of edges of $G$ is $E$ = ${k} \choose {2}$ + $n-k \choose 2$. Suppose $k$ is chosen such that $E$ is minimised, and suppose that $k>(n-k)+1$, that is $2k>n+1$. Then by moving a vertex from $G_{1}$ to $G_{2}$ and completing $G_{2}$ we lose $k-1-(n-k)=2k-n-1>(n+1)-n-1=0$ edges from $G$ which contradicts $E$ being minimum. If $k<(n-k)-1$, that is $2k<n-1$, then by moving a vertex from $G_{2}$ to $G_{1}$ we lose $(n-k-1)-(k)=n-2k-1>n-(n-1)-1>0$ edges from $G$ which again is a contradiction. Hence $k$ and $(n-k)$ differ by at most $1$. Hence $G$ has at least $\frac{\lfloor{n}\rfloor }{2} \choose 2$ + $\frac{\lceil{n}\rceil }{2} \choose 2$ edges. If $n$ is even, then this is $\frac{n}{2}.(\frac{n}{2}-1)$ as required. If $n$ is odd then this is $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{n-1}{2})(\frac{n-3}{2})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{n+1}{2})(\frac{n-1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{n-1}{2})(n-1) = \frac{n}{2}(\frac{n}{2}-1)-\frac{1}{4}(n-1)+\frac{n-1}{8}<\frac{n}{2}.(\frac{n}{2}-1)$

Answer (score 0):

With two complete connected components and $n$ vertices, there are not many possibilities for $G$. In fact, $G$ is uniquely defined by the order of either component. Let $k$ be the order of either component, the other has order $n-k$.

For a fixed $k$, the size $m_k$ of $G$ is the sum of the sizes of each component which are known as each component is complete:
$$
m_k = \frac{k(k-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)}{2}
$$

From there on, what is left to be done is showing that $\forall k \in \{0,\dots,n\}, m_k\geq \frac{n^2-2n}{4}$.